# How do you compare two strings in SQL and only get all of the letters that match?

Tags: sql, regex, string, db2, compare

I'm trying to write a formula in `SQL` that will look at 2 strings and the result is all of the letters that match.

*Edit*: Querying against **IBM DB2**

*Edit*: ABP compared to AP = AP

*Example:*

```
ABP compared to ABMP = ABP
MP compared to P = P
AP compared to BMP = P
ABP compared to AP = AP
```

Comment: ABP compared to AP = ?

Comment: Such things are better done in the programming language of your choice (and sql is no programming language).

Comment: I think ABP compared to AP = 'AP'

Comment: what you need is to write a function to convert string to character and store in a temp table & then you have compare that type of two tables...

Comment: I do believe I will work with my DBA and create a user-defined-function, based on the feedback that I have received thus far. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @tombom, of course SQl is a programming language, just because it isn't the one you prefer doesn't make it not a programming language. Yes it doesn't do this function well but other languages frankly do a pretty poor job of handling data too. The right tool for the right job and SQL is clearly the wrong tool to do this effectively. But it is still a programming language; it is just a specialized one.

Comment: Okay, it can be considered a programming language, but in my opinion it shouldn't be, because (again in my opinion) most features that make it a programming language were introduced to make up for poor database design and/or poor software design. And things like this above are in my opinion things that shouldn't be done on database layer. That's why I said it.

Comment: @tombom, my DBA said the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that SQL is well suited to this problem, you could really do with a programming language where you can compare character by character.

What database are you using, it may be an option to write a custom function to achieve what you want and allow the function to be called from within your SQL statement.

**UPDATE**

I believe that IBM DB2 offers a procedural extension which you could use to write customer functions as suggested above. Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with DB2 so I will not be able to help with this. I found the following link with some information for you:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0011916.htm

Comment: I will journey down this route. Thank you very much!

Comment: If he has SQL Server, a CLR stored proc might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the question does not completely specify the requirements, but as stated the problem can be solved, given this input:

```
create table Temp
(
 id int,
 val varchar(1000)
);

insert into temp values 
(1,'ABMPZ'),
(2,'AM');
```

with something like this:

```
with t (id, c, n) as (
  select id, substring(val,1,1), 1 from temp
  union all
  select t.id, substring(temp.val, t.n+1, 1), t.n+1 from t, temp
   where t.id=temp.id and t.n < 1000 and t.n < len(val)
  )
select t1.c from t t1, t t2
where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2 and t1.c = t2.c
```

[SQLFiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/69876/7/0)